# reason for using trace if I already use logger

Tags: java, debugging, trace

What is the reason to use trace ,I'm already using the logging but I'm not sure 
if I should use trace.

I found in the forum the way to use it but not the real reason ...

Comment: Uh, would you mind adding a link or otherwise making more specific what exactly you mean by "trace"? That word has quite a few different meanings depending on the context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can choose use or not use `TRACE` level logs. But you don't know the log level of these libs that your project depends on.

So that's not a problem whether you use it or not... All you need to know is that there is a log level lower than `DEBUG` called `TRACE`

Comment: Ok but why there are log and trace ,log I do use and I know the reason and I understand that the trace is used when you debug the code and activate it ,but what is the added value that we are getting from it ?

Comment: @StefanStrooves: *"why there are log and trace"*: you seem to imply that there is some fundamental difference between the two, apart from the verbosity level. That makes me doubt what you mean by the word "trace". Could you *please* edit your question to add a link to that forum post that started all this, so that we are all on the same page?